# How to do validation in html table using js in CodeIgniter

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I am doing validation for html table. If I didn't select one value which viewed in front end table it shows alert message.

I tried lot but not working.

***JS Code:***

```
$('#save_exit').click(function () {

    $('#tb > tbody > tr').each(function() {
        var hours = $(this).find('#hours').val();
        var minutes = $(this).find('#minutes').val();
    });

    if(hours != 0 && $minutes != 0 )
    {
        return true;
    } 

    alert("Please select .");
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not look for `id`'s in the loop, look in parent id, it's far enough.

```
$('#save_exit').click(function() {

  var hours = $('#tb').find('#hours').val();
  var minutes = $('#tb').find('#minutes').val();
  
  if (Number(hours) !== 0 && Number(minutes) !== 0) {
    return true;
  }

  alert("Please select .");
  return false;
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hirdbluebird/6xv7brck/13/)